Monthly data to daily - cubic spline interpolation in Python with optimisation
Working with some monthly data here, for example -



Month
Value




01/10/2024
100


01/11/2024
150


01/12/2024
400



now please keep in mind that the values are daily averages for the month in question.
The end goal is a DataFrame with daily values for 1st October 2024 to 31st December 2024, which have cubicly splined/connected the monthly averages, but here's the catch - SUCH THAT daily average values come out to the original monthly average.
I am able to use a cubic spline interpolation method to create a daily forecast from these values, i.e.
# data has been pre processed so that monthly values are at the midpoint for each month and other dates are empty

start_date = df.index.min()
end_date = df.index.max()
date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=date_range, columns=['Month'])
new_df.set_index('Month', inplace=True)

for col in df.columns:
    cs = CubicSpline(df.dropna().index.values, df[col].dropna().values)
    new_df[col] = cs(new_df.index.values)


you get the gist.
The problem is that I want to optimise the result so that when I take an average of the daily values, they come to the original monthly value.
I appreciate this may be a statistical question more than a coding one. I understand WHY this is happening - it's because the monthly averages on either side of November (in this example) are not equidistant from the November midpoint, i.e. the ramp up into December is steeper so the true average has been dragged up.
Is there an optimisation available to me in scipy.interpolate or another package than can do this?

Your question is a bit verbose. Is your goal to produce daily data by fitting a spline to monthly data, such that if you take the mean of the resulting daily data within a given month gives you exactly one of the very points you use to fit the spline in the first place?

Interesting question, but since it's mostly conceptual, it's better suited to [stats.SE]. To handle it carefully, consider that cubic spline interpolation is essentially just writing out equations for overlapping cubic polynomials and then solving for coefficients under some constraints (namely matching values and derivatives where two intervals meet). You can do the same thing, imposing different constraints, such as that the total area under the curve equals the mean times the length of the interval. I don't know how that will play out; good luck and have fun.

@CrisPlusPlus that's exactly it!

After some searching, the only existing solution that I have found so far is a Matlab function to interpolate a number of points for a time series: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263962/solid-line-from-a-local-average-series/269505#269505 which is constructing a cubic spline constrained to have the specified mean values and then sampling a number of points from it.

As Robert implies in the comments, a proper algorithm to do what you want is not something you can find in standard libraries. A quick search on the topic throws some interesting results like https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X06001703, which proves that adding uncommon constraints to the derivation of the spline coefficients isn't something unheard of. Specifically, Chapter 2 of that paper talks about fixing the average of interpolating data to a fixed value. I haven't read the details but it appears that most of their lemmas apply to linear interpolation only.
If you're math skills are up to the challenge, you should first try to understand and derive usual cubic splines, then add your constraint following a similar strategy to that in the paper.
